# Is there a command to move your character?

Tags: dota-2

I am searching for a command to use in the console to move my hero (optional: to a specific location).

My reference is: http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Console_Command_List

But it is outdated.

Does anyone have an idea how to archive this?

Comment: Move where?
There's no command to walk to a specific coordinate if thats what your after.

Comment: I'm guessing that there is, otherwise the bots would be impossible to code. Whether that's publicly accessible through the API is another story. I would take a look here: http://dev.dota2.com/showthread.php?t=75439. As you can see, there is a bot under the "MoveTo" command. More specifically I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks, that is some neat info. Maybe i should write ChrisC directly to get further information. (Will test around with that command for now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found a way to do it:

```
alias "myLeftclick" "+sixense_left_click; -sixense_left_click"

alias "myMove" "mc_move; myLeftclick"
bind "B" "myMove"
```

### Explanation:

`myLeftclick` uses the sixense commands from valve which allow to simulate a leftclick (+ for pressing down and - for releasing it)

`mc_move` is the move command. (it changes your mouse cursor to reflect that you pressed this command.) it expects a destination (a click anywhere on the map or minimap).

now we combine both into one command `myMove` and bind this to `B`

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly this does when you left click and press b?

Comment: in the old code you needed to release B to do the leftclick command. holding B would only do mc_move. i changed this to make the code more straight forward

Comment: `leftclick` is just a variablename not the real leftclick you do with your mouse. i could have named that `myLeftClick` too. so you just use `B` and your char moves where your mouse is